# Can anyone post the c++ code for joystick in cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, ios, cocos2d-iphone

cant find the way to implement a joystick in cocos2d-x. can anyone post any program they created with implementation of joystick in c++ framework

Comment: And you've tried *what* so far?

Answer (score 3):

Here you can find somethings:

http://www.gomonkey.it/2011/12/cocos-2d-sneakyjoystick/
http://gohighbeta.com/code/sneakyinput-avirtual-joypad-for-ios/